# compare xml with data in database

Tags: c#, xml, database, compare

I need advice on how to compare xml files with the data stored in the database. I have the following piece of code ...

```
namespace NacitanieXML
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

`List<string[]> konecneHodnoty = new List<string[]>();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XmlNodeType type;
        string[] pieces;
        string[] riadky;

        using(XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("gps.kml"))
        {
            foreach (string[] pom in konecneHodnoty)
            {
                string prvaHodnota = pom[0];
            }
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                type = reader.NodeType;
                if (type == XmlNodeType.Element)
                {
                    if (reader.Name == "coordinates")
                    {
                        reader.Read();
                        string pozicie = reader.Value;
                        riadky = pozicie.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

                        foreach (string riadok in riadky)
                        {
                            if (riadok != String.Empty)
                            {
                                pieces = riadok.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                                konecneHodnoty.Add(pieces);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            reader.Close();
            }

        }
}`

}

Each line of the XML document has three parts now, and I need to compare the first and second value of data in the database.

I have a table in the database - Tab_Position - and her columns lat and lon. I think I need a loop to navigate database data, or somehow through select?

MessageBox is open for identity data.

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you include what your XML looks like? Also I'm not sure what you are trying to do here: `foreach (string[] pom in konecneHodnoty)` but its not actually going to do anything. Its setting the value of a string scoped internally to the foreach to a set value. If the string was declared outside of the loop, it would still overwrite all values  to the last pom[0]

Comment: just curious what language are your variables in?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2'>
<Document>
<Folder>
<Placemark>
<visibility>1</visibility>
<name></name>
<description></description>
<Style>
<IconStyle>
<Icon>
<href>http://www.zonefivesoftware.com/SportTracks/Images/SportTracksIcon48.png</href>
<w>48</w>
<h>48</h>
</Icon>
</IconStyle>
<geomScale>10</geomScale>
<geomColor>ff0045ff</geomColor>
</Style>
<LineString>
<coordinates>
21.244303,48.962900,30
21.244125,48.962750,30
21.244043,48.962675,30
21.243967,48.962608,30</coordinates>
</LineString>
</Placemark>
</Folder>
</Document>
</kml>